# Star Wars error "use the force"

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part

Error when deploying a Visual Web Part:

> use the force attribute to explicitly re-install the feature.

Is the force not with me?  How do i use the force?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `Always Force Install` to True in for your feature. (Assuming you are using Visual Studio)...Check the feature property window and you should see this option!

If you are using PowerShell, you can also use :

```
$sln = Add-SPSolution mySolution.wsp
Install-SPSolution -Identity mySolution.wsp -GACDeployment -Force
```